# Find command in IBM AIX

Tags: bash, permissions, unix, aix

I would verify that files in the location listed may not have both the other-write and any execute permissions set.
This requirement to be applied recursively to files contained within subdirectories.
socket (s), named pipe (p), block special file (b), character special file (c), and symbolic link (l) files are excluded from this requirement.
i have this output with `find`:

```
bash-5.1# ls -ls /test/
total 8
   0 drwxr-x-w-    2 root     system          256 Apr 28 04:49 directory
   0 lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     system           11 Apr 28 04:57 symlink -> /test/test1
   4 -rw-r-----    1 root     system            6 Apr 24 04:33 tes
   4 -rwxr-x-w-    1 root     system           11 Apr 24 04:49 test1
   0 -rw-r---w-    1 root     system            0 Apr 18 20:45 test2
bash-5.1# find /test -type d,f \( -perm -o=w -a \( -perm -u=x -o -perm -g=x -o -perm -o=x \) \) -ls
12337    1 drwxr-x-w-  2 root      system         256 Apr 28 04:49 /test/directory
bash-5.1# find /test -type f,d \( -perm -o=w -a \( -perm -u=x -o -perm -g=x -o -perm -o=x \) \) -ls
12334    1 -rwxr-x-w-  1 root      system          11 Apr 24 04:49 /test/test1
```

As you can see when i change the order from `-type d,f` to -`type f,d` the result changes, i don't know why.
also i have this approach:

```
bash-5.1# find /test ! \( -type s -o -type p -o -type b -o -type c -o -type l \) \( -perm -o=w -a \( -perm -u=x -o -perm -g=x -o -perm -o=x \) \) -ls
12337    1 drwxr-x-w-  2 root      system         256 Apr 28 04:49 /test/directory
12334    1 -rwxr-x-w-  1 root      system          11 Apr 24 04:49 /test/test1
```

what do you think about the best approach please.

Comment: Per requirement this should apply only to files. for use `find /path -type f` only

Comment: You have tags `linux` and `ubuntu` but your title is for AIX. Which OS are you actually asking about?

Comment: Yes, @doneal24 .. the tags are clearly in conflict with the question itself.  Since this is POSIX, it shouldn't matter that much but I too desire clarity.

Comment: `-type d,f` is a GNU extension. Portably it's `\( -type d -o -type f \)`. If your `find` does not support the extension, *maybe* it only pays attention to the first character of `d,f` of `f,d`, hence the partial results.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas No, the command used is not POSIX so the tags do matter as does the particular version of find being used.

Comment: My bad @doneal24 .. I was thinking about the `ls` and the `find`.. not the type.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIX uses POSIX `find`, which does not support the GNU extension on `-type` that permits a list of types to match. Instead of `-file f,d` you would need to write the more portable `( -file f -o -file d )`. (For future reference, POSIX `find` also does not have `-perm /mode`, which means the permissions check is somewhat more long-winded than might be necessary with GNU `find`.)

You want files or directories that contain other-write *and* any execute permission:

```
find /test \( -type f -o -type d \) -perm -o=w \( -perm -u=x -o -perm -g=x -o -o=x \) -ls
```

Note, in most shells you'll need to escape the `(` and `)` characters with backslash (`\` ), as I have done here, so that they are passed directly to `find`.